# Whenever $f=T(x)$ then $f(x) \geq 0$. Prove $T$ is bounded by closed graph theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, closed-graph

Let X be a Banach space and suppose $T:X \rightarrow X^*$ is linear and has the property that whenever $f=T(x)$ then $f(x)\geq 0$. Prove T is bounded.

The book gives a hint: using closed graph theorem.

I stucked at proving $|T(x_n)-T(x)|=\sup_{\|y\|\leq1}|f_{x_n}(y)-f_x(y)|\rightarrow0$.

Any suggestion is appriciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $x_n\to0$ and suppose $T(x_n)\to F$, which is not zero. As such there must be some $y\in X$ with $F(y)>0$. Now:

$$0 ≤ T(\lambda y-x_n)\,[\lambda y - x_n] = \lambda^2 T(y)\,[y] - \lambda T(x_n)\,[y] + T(\lambda y- x_n)\,[x_n],$$
in particular the limit of this expresiion, which is equal to $\lambda^2 T(y)\,[y]- \lambda F(y)$, must be $≥0$ for all $\lambda$. For small $\lambda$ this is impossible, as $F(y)>0$.

This contradiction implies that the operator $T$ is closed.

Comment: Why this contradiction implies that the operator T is closed?

Comment: Closed means the following: If $x_n$ and $T(x_n)$ converge to $x$ and $y$ respectively, then $x$ is in the domain of $T$ and $T(x)=y$. For your operator the domain is all of $X$, so if you want to contradict closedness what you need is a convering sequence $x_n\to x$ with $T(x_n)\not\to T(x)$. By considering $\tilde x_n := x -x_n$ you get a sequence converging to $0$ with $T(\tilde x_n)\not\to T(x)-T(x) = 0$.

Comment: How can we know that $T(x_n)$ converges to some $F$? Is it possible that $T(x)$ does not converge at all? Thanks!

Comment: Because that is the situation of the closed graph theorem. If we want the graph to be closed we need that whenever $x_n$ and $T(x_n)$ _both_ converge one has $y=T(x)$. If we want to assume that the graph is not closed and get a contradiction we should assume that $x_n$ and $T(x_n)$ _both_ converge, but $y\neq T(x)$.